# Facebook login with omniauth not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth, facebook-login

I am newbie trying to add facebook login to my rails app using omniauth & 2 and omniauth-facebook. I followed the instructions on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview.

But it is showing me the below error now, I have searched around the net and tried many different ways without much success, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, so can I someone help me with this? much appreciated.

Running on

rails (3.2.12) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.1) 
Using omniauth (1.1.4) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)

Error:
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
    Couldn't find User with id=sign_up

My code

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,                  :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :provider, :uid, :name
 attr_accessible :title, :date_of_birth, :firstName, :lastName, :mailId, :phone, :provider, :uid

protected

 def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.find(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
unless user
  user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
 end
 user
end  

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
super.tap do |user|
  if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
    user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
  end
 end
end

 has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
```

end

devise.rb

```
 require 'devise/orm/active_record'
 require 'omniauth-facebook'

 config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/users/auth"
 config.omniauth :facebook,  "XXXX", "XXXX", {:client_options => { :ssl => { :verify => false } }}
 end
```

routes.rb

```
Dine::Application.routes.draw do
 get "home/index"


 resources :pins
 resources :pin 
 resources :users

match '/auth/facebook' => 'omniauth#passthru'

devise_scope :user do
get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } , :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

root :to => 'pins#index'
get 'about' => 'pages#about'
get 'weekly' => 'pages#weekly'
get 'shop' => 'pages#shop'
get 'service' => 'pages#service'
get 'privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
get 'test' => 'pages#test'
get 'recipies' => 'pages@recipies'  

match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
end
end
```

OmniauthCallbacksController

```
 class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def passthru
send(params[:provider]) if providers.include?(params[:provider])
end

protected

def facebook
raise "Implement me for facebook"
end

def twitter
raise "Implement me for twitter"
end

private

def providers
["facebook", "twitter"]
end
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @pins = @user.pins.page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
 end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h2>登入</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
<%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
</div>

 <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: your error is in UsersController's show method. maybe you should post that one...

Comment: @Miotsu, I've just updated with UserController. However, the tutorial never mentioned about changing anything in UserController though.

Comment: Ok, the error message you get is telling you that you pass 'sign_up' in your params[:id]. Have a look at the link/view/whatever is calling that method and double check the params you are passing.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea where to look for what is calling that method. Where is it likely to be at? It use to work fine before, but now I am trying to add Facebook login and it doesn't work, so it's not really making any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. from a terminal:

   bundle exec rake routes >> r.txt
2. open r.txt and look for the line containing `users#show`, note down the first term of that line, which should be something like user_show (let's call it `the_route`).
3. add `_path` to your route (eg. `the_route_path`) and search your whole project for that string.
4. somewhere in your project (most likely in a view) there will be a `link_to` or `redirect_to` `the_route_path` and I guess somewhere you will be passing `'sign_up'` as a `:id` param.
5. that's where the mistake is.

Comment: Hi Miotsu, thank you so much for helping me out. I've just updated the view new.html.erb above. I guess the problem came from  this line of code, but how do I fix it?
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>

Comment: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_id)) do |f| %>

Comment: Sorry, you want me to swap the above code in to new.html.erb?  I've tried it but it doesn't work still.

Comment: mmm... I guess you'll have to sort it out by yourself, you can't post your whole project. good luck with that.

Comment: Much appreciated, guess I am back at square one.